# Ember: Update ObjectController property from ArrayController action?

Tags: ember.js

Disclaimer:  I'm quite new to Ember.  Very open to any advice anyone may have.

I have a action in a ArrayController that should set an ObjectController property. How I can access the right context to set that property when creating a new Object?

Here is abbreviated app code show my most recent attempt:

```
ChatApp.ConversationsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  itemController: 'conversation',
  actions: {
    openChat: function(user_id, profile_id){
      if(this.existingChat(profile_id)){
        new_chat = this.findBy('profile_id', profile_id).get('firstObject');
      }else{
        new_chat = this.store.createRecord('conversation', {
          profile_id: profile_id,
        });
        new_chat.save();
      }
      var flashTargets = this.filterBy('profile_id', profile_id);
      flashTargets.setEach('isFlashed', true);
    }
  },
  existingChat: function(profile_id){
    return this.filterBy('profile_id', profile_id).get('length') > 0;
  }
});

ChatApp.ConversationController =  Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isFlashed: false
});
```

The relevant template code:

```
{{#each conversation in controller itemController="conversation"}}
  <li {{bind-attr class="conversation.isFlashed:flashed "}}>
    <h3>Profile: {{conversation.profile}} Conversation: {{conversation.id}}</h3>
    other stuff
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry that was an unneeded and vague reference. I meant that the property should be set in the action that's called. I just removed the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you need an object that handles setting a property for all the elements in your list. Have each item take care of itself, this means `components` time.

`Controllers` and `Views` will be deprecated anyway, so you would do something like:

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [...];
  }
});

App.ConversationComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  isFlashed: false,
  actions: {
    // handle my own events and properties
  }
});
```

and in your template

```
{{#each item in model}}
  {{conversation content=item}}
{{/each}}
```

So, whenever you add an item to the model a new component is created and you avoid having to perform the `existingChat` logic.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm moving away from Object/Array Controllers to use components.  I had a few more questions as I move in that direction, but I thought it was worth a separate question.  If you have any time to take a look, I'd love any additional feedback you may have! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294024/road-to-ember-2-0-high-level-ember-app-structure-feedback

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayController` and `ItemController` [are going to be depreciated](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/15). As you are new to Ember I think that it would be better for you not to use them and focus on applying to coming changes.

What I can advice you is to create some kind of proxy object that will handle your additional properties (as `isFlashed`, but also like `isChecked` or `isActive`, etc.). This proxy object (actually an array of proxy objects) can look like this (and be a computed property):

```
proxiedCollection: Ember.computed.map("yourModelArray", function(item) {
  return Object.create({
    content: item,
    isFlashed: false
  });
});
```

And now, your template can look like:

```
{{#each conversation in yourModelArray}}
  <li {{bind-attr class="conversation.isFlashed:flashed "}}>
    <h3>Profile: {{conversation.content.profile}} Conversation: {{conversation.content.id}}</h3>
    other stuff
  </li>
{{/each}}
```

Last, but not least you get rid of `ArrayController`. However, you would not use `filterBy` method (as it allows only one-level deep, and you would have the array of proxy objects, that each of them handles some properties you filtered by - e.g. id). You can still use explicit `forEach` and provide a function that handles setting:

```
this.get("proxiedCollection").forEach((function(_this) {
  return function(proxiedItem) {
    if (proxiedItem.get("content.profile_id") === profile_id) {
      return proxiedItem.set("isFlashed", true);
    }
  };
})(this));
```