# Road to Ember 2.0 - High level Ember app structure feedback?

Tags: ember.js

I find I'm trying to pick up learning Ember at a time of particular fluctuation.  The recent "Road to 2.0" blog post has helped me clarify which direction to head, but I'm struggling to validate my approach to Ember at a high level.

I want to be sensitive to people's time.  My [full code](https://gist.github.com/Rio517/b241acf9137173a5ff3e) is here for anyone interested in providing more specific feedback (would love), but **I'm mostly interested in this high level feedback on my app's structuring and my utilization of Ember's capabilities.**

#### App Background:

I'm working on a user-to-many chat to text SMS app.  Visually, each user has multiple chat windows (a `Conversation`) open w/ messages (`Message`) specific to a `Profile` message history. The rails backed sends messages to the target `Profile`. This project is very much in development.

#### Key Questions:

- What is the best way to associate a model with a component? I'm passing each conversation model to a conversation component. As my component logic becomes so tightly integrated to the view, tt seems like a component class is taking on too much heft outside of UI.  I'm starting to add of logic around how UI bubbles up to the model, but wonder if there are better approaches.
- Since I'm breaking away from the proxying behavior of Array controller, I find myself referencing my model collection via `this.get('content')` - is there a better way to deal with the collection of conversations?
- Finally, to invoke actions in a component, I've read of using `Ember.Evented` mixin to trigger and observe events. I.e. when a user tries to open a chat window for a profile when that chat is already open, I'd want to flash the target chat window.  Is this a good way to manage these interaction in context of "Road to 2.0"?
- What about passing events from the controller to the `Message` subcomponents? Message subcomponents would be bound to each messages' statuses (success, fail, etc). I imagine i'd just bind some message display to a record's state and status attribute. Any way I could do it better?

I'm super open to feedback.  Be harsh!  :)

#### High level code:

([full code](https://gist.github.com/Rio517/b241acf9137173a5ff3e))

```
ChatApp.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('conversations', { path: '/' });
});

ChatApp.ConversationsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () { //this is a collection of active conversations
  },
  activate: function() { //listens to event stream
  }
});

ChatApp.ConversationsController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    openChat: function(user_id, profile_id){ //open chat if one isn't open.
    }
  },
  removeExcessChats: function(){ // removes chats that don't fit in window
  },
});

ChatApp.ConversationHolderComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  actions: {
    markInactive: function(){
      // referencing a passed in conversation is the only way I know to reference the model.
      this.get('conversation').markInactive();
    },
    createMessage: function(){
    }
  },
  isFlashed: false
});
```

### Component templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/conversation-holder">
  <button {{action "markInactive"}}>close</button>
  <h3>Profile: {{conversation.profile}} Conversation: {{conversation.id}}</h3>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    {{#each message in conversation.messages}}
      <li><strong>{{message.type}}</strong> {{message.body}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    <li>
      <form class="form-inline" {{action "createMessage" on="submit"}}>
        {{input class="message_body" placeholder="Start typing a message..." value=conversation.new_message_body type="text"}}
        {{input class="btn" type="submit" value="Send"}}
      </form>
    </li>
  </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="conversations">
  <section id="todoapp">
    <header id="header">
      <h1>Chat Messaging</h1>
    </header>
  </section>

  <section id="main">
    <p>Open a new chat with profile id #1 <a href="#" {{action "openChat" 1 1}} >Open w/ profile 1</a> | <a href="#" {{action "openChat" 1 6}} >open profile already in convo</a></p>

    <ul id="chat-app"  class="list-unstyled clearfix">
      {{#each conversation in model}}
        <li>{{chat-holder conversation=conversation}}</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </section>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't go through your app design, but I'm answering based on the more general Ember concepts that you mentioned.

1.

There isn't really a model object in Ember. You have a route with a **model hook** that returns whatever you want as **your model**. It can be a string, array or just a number.

When you use Ember Data, what will happen is that the model hook returns Ember Data objects.

A component can receive any object as its model/content. So, there isn't a best or worst way of associating a model and component, you just pass it what it needs.

2.

If your component is starting to get too big, probably you should split it in two or more components. Nothing wrong with having a component's template render other components.

Also, if you have logic that is shared among many components, you can refactor that into a mixin and include it in each component.

3.

Your idea for message passing between the controller and the components is *probably* right. The usual flow in Ember apps is events up & data down. Since the controller is at a higher level than a component, you can't send event in that direction, but by updating bound values you can pass new info to the components.